# Xcode build fail

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(UITableViewRowAction!, NSIndexPath!) ->
>   Void' to expected argument type '(UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath) ->
>   Void'

Does anyone know what I can do to get rid of this error?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { 
        (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            let firstActivityItem = self.animals[indexPath.row]
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
            self.presentviewcontroller(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return [shareAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
(action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
```

with

```
(action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: IndexPath)
```

or, even better, simply

```
(action, indexPath)
```